# How to change height of line break in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

How can I change height of line break in math mode? I need to add more space between each two lines of the equation.

```
\begin{gather*}
    EFF_a = \sum_{j=0}^{2} (\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{4} (EFF_{{a_j}_i} = {\{ p_i; q_i}\}  \rightarrow p_i \cdot q_i)}{ \sum_{i=1}^{4} q_i } \cdot W_{EFF_{a_j})} =
    \\ = \frac{1 \cdot 15 + 2 \cdot 15 + (-1) \cdot 2}{15+15+2} \cdot 0.5 + \frac{1 \cdot 314 + 2 \cdot 101 + (-1) \cdot 33 + (-2) \cdot 4}{314+101+33+4} \cdot 0.4 +
    \\ + \frac{1 \cdot 23 + (-1) \cdot 33 }{23+33} \cdot 0.1 = 1.0743718394437423
\end{gather*}
```

This produces:

[image: equation]

Comment: Or you can add some vertical space manually`\begin{gather*}
    EFF_a = \sum_{j=0}^{2} (\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{4} (EFF_{{a_j}_i} = {\{ p_i; q_i}\}  \rightarrow p_i \cdot q_i)}{ \sum_{i=1}^{4} q_i } \cdot W_{EFF_{a_j})} =
    \\[2em]= \frac{1 \cdot 15 + 2 \cdot 15 + (-1) \cdot 2}{15+15+2} \cdot 0.5 + \frac{1 \cdot 314 + 2 \cdot 101 + (-1) \cdot 33 + (-2) \cdot 4}{314+101+33+4} \cdot 0.4 +
    \\[2em] + \frac{1 \cdot 23 + (-1) \cdot 33 }{23+33} \cdot 0.1 = 1.0743718394437423
\end{gather*}`

Comment: @Bobyandbob right, I missed that question.

Comment: @Ice0cean thanks, That's what I was looking for.